# JBoss: Unmatched braces in the pattern

Tags: jboss

Our JBoss application recently encountered the following error. Anyone knows what might be the root causefor this error ?

```
WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLoggerI18N] (Thread-15) [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper_18] - TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX a891620:a058:55ff1fd9:47b in state  CANCEL
WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLoggerI18N] (Thread-15) [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper_18] - TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX a891620:a058:55ff1fd9:47b in state  CANCEL_INTERRUPTED
WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLoggerI18N] (Thread-15) [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper_6] - TransactionReaper::check worker Thread[Thread-133,5,jboss] not responding to interrupt when cancelling TX a891620:a058:55ff1fd9:47b -- worker marked as zombie and TX scheduled for mark-as-rollback
WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLoggerI18N] (Thread-15) [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper_11] - TransactionReaper::check failed to mark TX a891620:a058:55ff1fd9:47b  as rollback only



WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLoggerI18N] (Thread-15) [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper_18] - TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX a891620:a058:55ff1fd9:4c3 in state  CANCEL_INTERRUPTED
ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-15) Exception in thread "Thread-15" 
ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-15) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmatched braces in the pattern.
ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-15)  at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:476)
ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-15)  at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:350)
ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-15)  at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:811)
ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-15)  at com.arjuna.common.internal.util.logging.AbstractLogImpl.getString(AbstractLogImpl.java:641)
ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-15)  at com.arjuna.common.internal.util.logging.LogImpl.evalResourceBundle(LogImpl.java:974)
ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-15)  at com.arjuna.common.internal.util.logging.LogImpl.error(LogImpl.java:514)
ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-15)  at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper.check(TransactionReaper.java:397)
ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-15)  at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.coordinator.ReaperThread.run(ReaperThread.java:113)
```